# Solving munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error in c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to get used to the dynamic array in class to which I get the result to the output but get a core dump error.I get the output correct but at last of the output after compiling I get this core dump.

Output is

```
Enter the size of array: 4
Enter the numbers of array: 20
21
22
23
The element of the array is 
20
21
22
23
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the program I wrote:

```
class Array
{
  private:
    int *arr;
    int size;
  public:
    Array(int sizes, int at[])
    {
        size = sizes;
        arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = at[i];
        }
    }
    Array()
    {
        size = 0;
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor worked."; 
        delete[] arr;
    }
    void getarray()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the size of array: ";
        std::cin >> size;
        setsize(size);
        std::cout << "Enter the numbers of array: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> arr[i];
        }
    }
    void setsize(int sizes)
    {
        size = sizes;
    }
    void output(std::ostream& outs)
    {
        outs << "The element of the array is " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            outs << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I am still not good at dynamic array and I thought of using vectors. It will be great if anyone can show me what the problem with this problem is or any easier method for doing the same.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you use class `Array`.  At the very least `setsize` should probably check against the current size and reallocate if necessary.

Comment: This program just output the value entered by the user in an array

Comment: Another issue is that the default constructor does not initialize `arr`. Anyway, using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would indeed be much easier.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The default constructor has no need of initializing the array as its setting `size` to `0`.

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil That still doesn't initialize the pointer `arr`. Consider what happens if the destructor is called?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes, I totally agree. But the issue which might arise will be due to the wild pointer, and not the uninitialized array. A better solution (I feel) is to assign the value of `nullptr` to `arr`. `delete[] (int *)nullptr` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil Ah, I meant the default constructor does not initialize the pointer `arr`. So we indeed agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `main()` is somewhat like:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    Array foo; // or Array foo(bar, baz);
    foo.getarray();
    foo.output(std::cout);
}
```

The main problem here is that your constructor gets called before your `getarray()` method. And since you are already allocating memory inside your constructor,

```cpp
void getarray() {
    ...
    // Changing size, and iterating over it
    ...
}
```

is **dangerous**. If your `newSize > size`, the loop will try to access memory that does not belong to your program. If your `newSize < size`, it will not access all the elements.

---

### How to overcome this?

- Resize your array when you ask for `size` again.
- Do not allocate memory inside the constructor, but allocate it inside `getarr()`.
- Do not resize your array inside `getarray()` at all, in which case you should not change your `size`.

All this really depends on the functionality you want to achieve. Say you want to have a fixed-sized array for the entire duration of your program, using a `const` qualifier with your `size` will help restrict un-authorized modifications.

If you want arrays which dynamically grow and shrink during your execution, you are better off using the [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container.